# How to split the terminal in PhpStorm 2020.1?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I've read it's possible to split the terminal in PhpStorm 2020.1 in half. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im using IntelliJ, but it should be the same:

Right click on a terminal and choose if you want to split vertically or horizontally.

[image: split terminal]

Comment: I was talking about the console terminal actually, not the file window. Can you edit your answer? It's good to know I can do the same with files though lol.

Comment: Done, yes, with right click on a file name you can also split the window and then drag and drop files from one side to the other.